Anime/cartoon about a game where people collect elemental balls that house an animal inside
The cartoon or anime's idea is about a game where people basically collect balls of the same element. Each ball contains an animal that, once opened up, and fights the other. The winner then can collect the balls of the person that lost. The more you have, the more chances you have to win (e.g. you can have multiple "animal-balls" fight at the same time). I remember that the main character's element was fire.

Hi. Can you rule out any shows that have a similar premise to what you've described here, but aren't the one you're looking for? Pokemon, for example?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent chance to [edit] further details into your question, e.g. "I know that it isn't Ball Smasherz because the main character didn't have an anthropomorphized pillbug-girl as his main battler, and his girlfriend died in the first episode as the result of a tragic unrealized allergy to corn."

Might this be Bakugan: Battle Planet, the unaccepted answer here?


The season follows the adventures of Dan Kouzo and his best friends, the first kids on Earth to bond with the mysterious alien creatures known as the Bakugan. The storyline revolves around friendship, battling, and competition.

The main character, Dan Kouzo, is with the "Pyrus" faction, related to fire.
First episode



Found by searching for [story-identification] fight balls fire on this site, as I thought we had this one before.
